# get a list of containers in the storage account

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

with the code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("<storageaccountname>_AzureStorageConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test-blob-container");
```

I can access the Blob container “test-blob-container”. But is there a way to get a list of containers in the storage account?

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListContainers()` method is not supported in .NET Core library, which is by design since it's not an asynchronous method, but you can still leverage `ListContainersSegmentedAsync()` to list blob containers in .NET Core library:

```
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var blobContainers = new List<CloudBlobContainer>();
BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
do
{
    var containerSegment = await blobClient.ListContainersSegmentedAsync(blobContinuationToken);
    blobContainers.AddRange(containerSegment.Results);
    blobContinuationToken = containerSegment.ContinuationToken;
} while (blobContinuationToken != null);
```

Just like the REST API, segmented results are returned with a continuation token in case that the container listing can't be finished within only one API call. That's why `ListContainersSegmentedAsync()` is the only remaining method in .NET Core - it's the really asynchronous one which equals to one REST API call.